# Insert outer dict value to inner dict list

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a nested `dict` of lists and dicts I want to ultimately iterate through and output to a dataframe.

This sample dictionary has five items so I'm expecting a dataframe of five rows; however, it is doubling up and producing ten rows.

There are nested lists and dicts. I want to keep the outer values and include them in the inner-most list.

I have browsed too many StackOverflow posts to include, but I'm making a mistake somewhere in the iterations.

Any help to the specific question or how to better write this overall is appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

sample_dic = {'game_id': 'beeec03419b1aa196028a89f177f4324',
 'sportsbooks': [{'bookie_key': 'fanduel',
   'market': {'market_key': 'player_points_over_under',
    'outcomes': [{'timestamp': '2024-02-09T15:40:01',
      'handicap': 20.5,
      'odds': -122,
      'participant': 16142,
      'participant_name': 'Dejounte Murray',
      'name': 'Dejounte Murray Over',
      'description': 'Dejounte Murray - Points'},
     {'timestamp': '2024-02-09T15:57:49',
      'handicap': 21.5,
      'odds': -111,
      'participant': 16142,
      'participant_name': 'Dejounte Murray',
      'name': 'Dejounte Murray Over',
      'description': 'Dejounte Murray - Points'},
     {'timestamp': '2024-02-09T15:57:49',
      'handicap': 15.5,
      'odds': -125,
      'participant': 17163,
      'participant_name': 'Jalen Johnson',
      'name': 'Jalen Johnson Over',
      'description': 'Jalen Johnson - Points'}]}},
  {'bookie_key': 'draftkings',
   'market': {'market_key': 'player_points_over_under',
    'outcomes': [{'timestamp': '2024-02-09T13:09:03',
      'handicap': 18.5,
      'odds': -200,
      'participant': None,
      'participant_name': None,
      'name': 'Over - Dejounte Murray',
      'description': ' Alt Points O/U'},
     {'timestamp': '2024-02-09T15:21:11',
      'handicap': 15.5,
      'odds': -225,
      'participant': None,
      'participant_name': None,
      'name': 'Over - Kelly Oubre Jr.',
      'description': ' Alt Points O/U'}]}}]}

outcomes_list = []
v_game_id = sample_dic['game_id']
v_prop = sample_dic['sportsbooks'][0]['market']['market_key']
for i in range(0, len(sample_dic['sportsbooks'])):
  book = sample_dic['sportsbooks'][i]['bookie_key']
  for s in sample_dic['sportsbooks']:
    for k, v in s.items():
      if k == 'market':
        for k2, v2 in v.items():
          if k2 == 'outcomes':
            for o in v2:
              # outcomes_list.append(o) # This works for the inner 'outcomes' list only
              # Adding game_id, sportsbook, and prop k/v pairs back in
              new_dic = {'game_id': v_game_id, 'sportsbook': book, 'prop': v_prop}
              new_dic.update(o)
              outcomes_list.append(new_dic)
              
# Then to df
# This has doubled-up rows
outcomes_df = pd.DataFrame(outcomes_list)
outcomes_df
```

[image]

To show how the dataframe should look like, it can be manually produced like so:

```
wanted_outcomes_list = [['beeec03419b1aa196028a89f177f4324',
  'fanduel',
  'player_points_over_under',
  '2024-02-09T15:40:01',
  20.5,
  -122,
  16142,
  'Dejounte Murray',
  'Dejounte Murray Over',
  'Dejounte Murray - Points'],
 ['beeec03419b1aa196028a89f177f4324',
  'fanduel',
  'player_points_over_under',
  '2024-02-09T15:57:49',
  21.5,
  -111,
  16142,
  'Dejounte Murray',
  'Dejounte Murray Over',
  'Dejounte Murray - Points'],
 ['beeec03419b1aa196028a89f177f4324',
  'fanduel',
  'player_points_over_under',
  '2024-02-09T15:57:49',
  15.5,
  -125,
  17163,
  'Jalen Johnson',
  'Jalen Johnson Over',
  'Jalen Johnson - Points'],
 ['beeec03419b1aa196028a89f177f4324',
  'draftkings',
  'player_points_over_under',
  '2024-02-09T13:09:03',
  18.5,
  -200,
  None,
  None,
  'Over - Dejounte Murray',
  ' Alt Points O/U'],
 ['beeec03419b1aa196028a89f177f4324',
  'draftkings',
  'player_points_over_under',
  '2024-02-09T15:21:11',
  15.5,
  -225,
  None,
  None,
  'Over - Kelly Oubre Jr.',
  ' Alt Points O/U']]

wanted_outcomes_df = pd.DataFrame(wanted_outcomes_list, columns=['game_id', 'sportsbook', 'prop', 'timestamp', 'handicap', 'odds', 'participant', 'participant_name', 'name', 'description'])
wanted_outcomes_df
```

[image]

Comment: Where are the duplicates in the result? The first 3 columns are duplicates, but other columns are different.

Comment: Since you start with a dictionary, is data reshaping via pandas a requirement or can you reshape the data and load the resulting 5 rows of dictionaries into pandas?

Comment: The duplicates are the rows: each `prop` is getting a row per `sportsbook` ... For example, the first record is getting a 'FanDuel' and 'DraftKings' row but should only be the former.

Reshape however. I figured it would be easier to append list/dictionaries and make the final transformation to a pandas df. I will look at the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm not a pandas expert, particularly when it comes to loading hierarchical data where more than one `record_path` and/or `meta` is needed, I would reshape the data "by hand", then load it into pandas.

Given your data (`sample_dic`), I would reshape it via:

```
results = []
for sportsbook in sample_dic["sportsbooks"]:
    market = sportsbook["market"]
    for outcome in  market["outcomes"]:
        results.append({
            **{"game_id": sample_dic["game_id"], "bookie_key": sportsbook["bookie_key"], "market_key": market["market_key"]},
            **outcome
        })
```

Then you can take that and do what you want with it...

```py
import json
for result in results:
    print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

```
{
    "game_id": "beeec03419b1aa196028a89f177f4324",
    "bookie_key": "fanduel",
    "market_key": "player_points_over_under",
    "timestamp": "2024-02-09T15:40:01",
    "handicap": 20.5,
    "odds": -122,
    "participant": 16142,
    "participant_name": "Dejounte Murray",
    "name": "Dejounte Murray Over",
    "description": "Dejounte Murray - Points"
}
{
    "game_id": "beeec03419b1aa196028a89f177f4324",
    "bookie_key": "fanduel",
    "market_key": "player_points_over_under",
    "timestamp": "2024-02-09T15:57:49",
    "handicap": 21.5,
    "odds": -111,
    "participant": 16142,
    "participant_name": "Dejounte Murray",
    "name": "Dejounte Murray Over",
    "description": "Dejounte Murray - Points"
}
{
    "game_id": "beeec03419b1aa196028a89f177f4324",
    "bookie_key": "fanduel",
    "market_key": "player_points_over_under",
    "timestamp": "2024-02-09T15:57:49",
    "handicap": 15.5,
    "odds": -125,
    "participant": 17163,
    "participant_name": "Jalen Johnson",
    "name": "Jalen Johnson Over",
    "description": "Jalen Johnson - Points"
}
{
    "game_id": "beeec03419b1aa196028a89f177f4324",
    "bookie_key": "draftkings",
    "market_key": "player_points_over_under",
    "timestamp": "2024-02-09T13:09:03",
    "handicap": 18.5,
    "odds": -200,
    "participant": null,
    "participant_name": null,
    "name": "Over - Dejounte Murray",
    "description": " Alt Points O/U"
}
{
    "game_id": "beeec03419b1aa196028a89f177f4324",
    "bookie_key": "draftkings",
    "market_key": "player_points_over_under",
    "timestamp": "2024-02-09T15:21:11",
    "handicap": 15.5,
    "odds": -225,
    "participant": null,
    "participant_name": null,
    "name": "Over - Kelly Oubre Jr.",
    "description": " Alt Points O/U"
}
```